# Run-time error only after successful runs - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA macro that works successfully the first two times I run it, but the third time it gives this error:

> Run-Time Error '1004'
>
> The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.

If I restart Excel it works the first two times, then gives the error again. Why would this happen? Here's my code:

```
Dim rawData As Object
Dim report As Object
Dim areaCodes As Object
Set rawData = Sheets("RawData")
Set report = Sheets("Report")
Set areaCodes = Sheets("AreaCodes")

report.Cells.Clear
report.Cells.ClearFormats

stateCol = rawData.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="state", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = rawData.Cells(1, stateCol)

With rawData
    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Cells(2, stateCol), .Cells(lastRow, stateCol)).Copy
End With

With report
    .Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End With

lastRow = report.Cells(Rows.Count, Range("A1").Column).End(xlUp).Row

report.Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(rawData!C[" & stateCol - 2 & "],report!RC[-1])"
Range("B3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
Range("B" & lastRow + 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & lastRow - 2 & "]C:R[-1]C)"

Range("C3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/R" & lastRow + 1 & "C[-1]"
Range("C3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("C3:C" & lastRow)
Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & lastRow - 2 & "]C:R[-1]C)"
Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "0.0%"

Range("A2:A" & lastRow + 1).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

report.Range("A2").Value = "State"
report.Range("A2").Font.Bold = True
report.Range("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

report.Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(areaCodes!R2C5:R52C5,MATCH(report!RC[1],AreaCodes!R2C6:R52C6,0))"
Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:A" & lastRow)

With report
    newLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, Range("C1").Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(newLastRow, 3)).Copy
    .Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End With

With report
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    newLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, Range("C1").Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    With .Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:D" & newLastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

you should qualify the range in your sort instruction, this will produce an error if the sheet report is not activated

```
With report
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("C2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    newLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, .Range("C1").Column).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    With .Sort
        .SetRange report.Range("A2:D" & newLastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem. I've only been testing it with the report sheet activated, and the same behavior persists even after specifying report.Range

Comment: I solved my problem. I just needed to add `.Sort.SortFields.Clear` at the top of my `With` Statement